# Opening Landsat-8 GEOTIFF in Python?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, landsat-8, anaconda

I've run into an error when trying to open a Landsat-8 geotiff file in python, it seems like I am missing some tiff libraries but I'm not sure how to install them or where they need to go. Has anyone else encountered this issue when working with geotiff files?

I'm using the Anaconda 3.6 distribution of python on a windows 10 64 bit computer.

Python code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
path = "LC80040472015120LGN00_B4.TIF"
geotiff = gdal.Open(path)
```

Error Message:

> Warning 1: LC80040472015120LGN00_B4.TIF:AdobeDeflate compression
> support is not configured
>
> ERROR 1: Cannot open TIFF file due to
> missing codec.

Edit1:

Here is the index page on AWS for the image that I'm trying to open.

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/landsat-pds/L8/004/047/LC80040472015120LGN00/index.html

Comment: what does `gdalinfo LC80040472015120LGN00_B4.TIF` return when run from the cli?

Comment: Is your image public? It would be interesting to have a look. Interesting discussion in https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2164244

Comment: I created a deflate compressed tiff with GDAL and it is using Compression Scheme: AdobeDeflate. So no need for sample data. You seem to miss a common zip codec. Unfortunately I do not know how to add it.

Comment: @dmci Here is the cli output from gdalinfo: [link](http://imgur.com/a/wRHPd)

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed the problem by updating:

gdal 2.1.3 -> 2.2.0

libtiff 4.0.6vc14_3 -> libtiff 4.0.6vc14_7

Somehow this added the compression support.